# Trying make element display block with media query

Tags: html, css

here is a for a element in div. I use media query to make them centered and inline in full width i mean min-width 701px and make them blocked displaying under 700px. Centering works but it isn't being showed in Block display,rather in one line. But i wrote: display: block !important; in .kdown  demo: http://buhehe.de/kalender-2018/  i mean download buttons under the calendar
html:

```
<div class="kdown" id="kdown">  
  <h6> Kalender 2018 Ausdrucken , Download als PDF, Word, Excel oder PNG:</h6>
  <a target="_blank" class="pngg" href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/kalender-2018.png">
      <img src="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/png-img.png" alt="PNG" />
      <span>Download in PNG</span>
  </a>
  <a class="pdff" target="_blank" href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/kalender-2018.pdf"> 
      <img src="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/pdf-img.png" alt="PDF" />
      <span>Download in PDF</span> 
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" class="wordd" href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/kalender-2018.docx">
      <img src="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/word-img.png" alt="Word" />
      <span>Download in Word</span>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" class="excell" href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/kalender-2018.xlsx"> 
      <img src="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Excel-img.png" alt="Excel" />
      <span>Download in Excell</span>
  </a> 
</div>
```

css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
     .traki {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
         text-align: center !important;
    }
     .kdown p span {
        position: relative;
         top: -1px !important;
    }
     .kdown h6 {
         font-size: 15px !important;
    }
     .kdown p {
         display: block !important;
    }
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 701px) {
     .kdown p {
         display: inline !important;
    }
     .kdown {
         text-align: center !important;
    }
}
.kdown a {
     width: 160px;
     background-color: #FF9900;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     border-radius: 4px !important;
     height:40px;
     padding: 10px 3px 10px 5px ;
}
 .kdown a:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
 .kdown a:hover {
     opacity: 0.8;
     color: #ffffff !important;
}
 .kdown p img {
     width: 25px;
     padding-right: 3px;
     height: 25px;
     position: relative;
     top: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to center the buttons you want something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .kdown > p > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

using auto margins in a block element centers it.

Comment: That's what my solution does. ">" is a child selector. so all your "a" tags will be block and centered under 700. If I've misunderstood something let me know.

Comment: No u understood well but check page, i updated with your code. Only first a element is centered.

Comment: Can you get rid of this style? .kdown a:not(:first-child){ margin-lefft: 3px}? If not, you'll have to override my style with higher priority selectors.

Answer (score 0):

There's something weird, your stated HTML does not match the one in the webpage. Inspecting there gives a total spaghetti that runs the deprecated "font" tag, with no relation between the buttons and it's contents... Trying to set proper CSS would be magic.

Try to use a layout that makes more logical sense. Something like:

```
buttons-container
  button
     a
        img
        text
  button
     a
        img
        text
  button
     a
        img
        text
```

Then you can set the container to display flex, style the button as needed, set the A to 100% with and height so they work all over the button, and style the text and img as needed.

Here's a [little fiddle to get you started](https://jsfiddle.net/facundocorradini/dpm8vedz/), you can work from there ;)
Maybe switching flex-direction from row to column and adjusting the flex properties will be all you need ;)